# CreateProcess Failed, unexpected error

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to create process(calc.exe), but the program does not run correctly. It just crashes after start. I thing the problem is with LPWSTR variable, but I don't have idea how to fix it.

Below is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void NewProcess(LPWSTR cmd) {

    printf("Argv Inside funcion: %s\n", cmd[1]);
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, 
        cmd,      
        NULL,  
        NULL,  
        FALSE,    
        0,             
        NULL,      
        NULL,      
        &si,         
        &pi)          
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    printf("Process ID: %d Started", pi.dwProcessId);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    printf("\nProcess ID: %d Terminated!", pi.dwProcessId);


    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

void main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{   
    char text[] = "calc.exe";
    wchar_t wtext[20];
    mbstowcs(wtext, text, strlen(text) + 1);
    LPWSTR ptr = wtext;

    NewProcess(ptr); 
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: C and C++ aren't the same languages. Tag only with the appropriate one.

Comment: Exactly where does it crash? If you run the program under a debugger it should tell you the exact code location and the sequence of function calls leading to that location (call stack).

Comment: Solved...my bad. Sory. The problem was in wprintf("Argv Inside funcion: %s\n", cmd[1]); I missed  this line druing editid code, and there was a problem with cmd[1], because cmd was array before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf` is interpreting the first character of the command as a pointer to a (non-wide) C string.

Use

```
wprintf(L"Argv Inside funcion: %s\n", cmd);
```

and you don't need to complicate `main` so much (there are no multibyte characters in `"calc.exe"`, so there's nothing to convert):

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{   
    auto application[] = L"calc.exe";
    NewProcess(application); 
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I missed this line during editing code. Thanks

Comment: But I have one more question. Is is good practise to use "mbstowcs(wtext, text, strlen(text) + 1);" function ? When I was looking for the solution, there were other ways to initialize LPWSTR var, but not this way. This is weird for me because this function looks more friendly than other ways.

Comment: @bielu000 Just use a wide string literal: `wchar_t wtext[] = L"calc.exe";`. The `ptr` variable is also obsolete because arrays decay to pointer automatically, just call `NewProcess(wtext)`.

Comment: It should be `wprintf(L"Argv Inside funcion: %s\n", cmd);`

Comment: Literals are not writeable so the call to CreateProcess will fail. It requires a writeable string as the second arg.